# How to add to an object to a list inside a database via API post method

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

So I have 2 classes here:

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    public string Username { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Message> Messages { get; set; }

}
```

and

```
public class Message
{
    [Key]
    public int MessageId { get; set; }

    public string MessageContent { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }

    public int SenderId { get; set; }

    public int ReceiverId { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to create a message via the following controller action, which creates a new message and adds it to the database, and then update the ICollectionMessages inside the database.

Controller here:

```
    [Route("sendMessage")]
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task SendMessage([FromBody] Message message)
    {
        var newMessage = new Message
        {
            MessageContent = message.MessageContent,
            DateCreated = DateTime.Now,
            SenderId = message.SenderId,
            ReceiverId = message.ReceiverId

        };

        _dbContext.Messages.Add(newMessage);

        var user = _dbContext.Users.SingleOrDefault(x => x.UserId == message.SenderId);

        if(user != null)
        {
            var userMessages = user.Messages.ToList();
            userMessages.Add(newMessage);
        }


        await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();

    }
```

however I am getting a 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' error and I believe this to be because 'var userMessages = user.Messages.ToList();' is NULL and therefore cannot add a value to a null list.

Having a massive brainfog, can someone suggest a way around this?

edit:

my goal is to make USERID update:

[image: dbo.Messages]

Comment: You need explicitly load messages for the user `_dbContext.Users.Include(u => u.Messages).SingleOrDefault(x => x.UserId == message.SenderId);`

Comment: I think that you add a message to a copy of the `messages` collection (because of `ToList`), so try to do `user.Messages.Add(newMessage)`

Comment: amazing!thank you so much that worked beautifully!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You add a new message to a copy of the messages collection

```
var userMessages = user.Messages.ToList()
```

The above statement creates a brand new list for the data, so I would call it like

```
 user.Messages.Add(newMessage);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing like this

```
//your code...
var userMessages = user.Messages;
userMessages.Add(newMessage);
//your code...
```

Comment: i dont get the error and the message posts, but it doesnt update the userId in the database. UserId is still NULL

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    public string Username { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Message> Messages { get; set; } = new Collection<Message>();

}
```

so collection is always present,

```
   ...
   var user = _dbContext.Users.Include(u=>u.Messages).SingleOrDefault(x => x.UserId == message.SenderId);

   if(user != null)
   {
      var userMessages = user.Messages;
      userMessages.Add(newMessage);
   }

   await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
```

include messages, when finding user and use collection directly when adding new.

Comment: hey, thanks for the input but this doesnt seem to work. UserId doesnt update. Please see my edit for more detail on what I am trying to achieve

Comment: `userId` depends on how you have set up the Identity on you ModelBuilder/DbContext. Update your question with your DbContext.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you add a message to a copy of the messages collection (because of ToList), so try to do user.Messages.Add(newMessage)

user.Messages.Add(newMessage)

fixed by E. Shcherbo

thanks!